# Recursion function not returning

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to find an element in a tree and return it. It **works for the 1st level** and returns the desired folder, but when I try to get deeper it won't return, although it enters in the `return folder`, because if I `console.log(folder)` it shows me the found folder.

```
function findFolder(folders, folderId) {
    for (let i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
        const folder = folders[i]
        if (folder.id == folderId) {
            console.log(folder)
            return folder
        } else if (!folder.folders.length) {
            findFolder(folder.folders, folderId)
        }
    }
}
```

`console.log` showing it finds the 2nd lvl element, but won't return it when I first call the function:

`const found = findFolder(projectFolders, folderId)`

[image: console.log]

Comment: You should do `return findFolder(folder.folders, folderId)`

Comment: it is not sufficient just to return the recursive call, because in the firstt loop, if not found, it ends with unwanted result.

Comment: use `const temp = findFolder(folder.folders, folderId); if (temp) return temp;`

Comment: @NinaScholz just did it and it worked. Thaks a lot (:

Answer (score 0):

in your else if clause you have to return the findFolder call

Comment: Just did it, and the result is the same